# Check out an existing Remote Branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-checkout

I am new to GIT. Please help me, I am stuck at this point.

In my Remote Repository (github.com), already a branch by name code-267 is present which was created by a different developer.

My requirement: I need to check in that branch into my Eclipse.

Please tell me if can I execute the below statement, so that I will code of branch  code-267  ??

```
git checkout --track -b code-267 origin/code-267
```

Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Command seems to be ok - why don't you just try it?

Comment: dont know if it deletes the existing branch ?? and creates a new one .

Comment: @PreethiJain If you already have a branch named `code-267` on your computer and it does not track the remote one, you can move it to some other name using `git branch -m <oldname> <newname>`. Otherwise checking out the remote branch will not delete anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually:

```
git fetch # Get all updates and branches
git checkout code-267
```

will work fine.
Branch are deleted with the -D flag so as long as you do NOT use that you will not delete anything and you will be OK.  If you did delete a branch by mistake you would still be OK as long as you didn't push that change to github.